# MS Access: Add Const Value to Table from Different Table

Tags: ms-access

I am building a simple invoice form in MS Access and have two tables that I am trying to link data across. One is a `product` table, which includes the `price` field. However, because the price can change at any point, I want to store the price at the time of sale in my `line_item` table as a constant, unchanging value.

Furthermore, I want to be able to lock both of the values in the `invoice form` so neither is able to be changed. Because of this, I don't want my `sale_price` entry in the `line_item` table to be manually entered. I want it to pull from the `product` table's `price` entry.

However, I have yet to find any documentation to help me achieve this exact result.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common requirement.

Set textbox properties Enabled No and Locked Yes and TabStop No.

To retrieve the price it can be included as a column of combobox where product is selected.

Save the price into record with code behind the combobox AfterUpdate event. It can be done with a macro but I use VBA, ex: 
`Me!sale_price = Me.cbxProduct.Column(x)` - for x reference the column index with the price, index begins with 0.